# How to place in image in different place of UIImageView using Objective-C?

Tags: ios

I am new to this field.
This is the code. I have stored images in array. And in `UIViewController` I placed 6 `UIImageView`.

```
images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

    NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
    NSLog(@"%@",dd);
```

I need to place the images in different location, how to do?

Comment: ya you can set like yourimagename.image = images[index]

Comment: "I need to place the images in different location how to do?" What does that mean ? Different location of UIView ?? Or different ViewControllers??